# How to listen to changes in instance of a class object in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how are you?

I'm trying to listen to the changes in an instance of a Class object in a React App. I can see that the value of the class changes, but i can't get a useEffect to listen to this changes!

The class itself is pretty simple:

```
class Person {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.hunger = 0;
  }

  increaseHunger() {
    this.hunger += 10;
  }
}

export default Person;
```

Then i have my React App component:

```
import React from "react";
import Person from "./classes/Person";

export default function App() {
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState(new Person("John"));

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Effect");
  }, [person.hunger]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{person.name}</div>
      <div>{person.hunger}</div>
      <button onClick={() => person.increaseHunger()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Whenever i click the button, i can see the log inside the class functions and i can see that the hunger changes, but the log in the useEffect functions never triggers. I think that perhaps the reference of the person object in the React component is not changing, but i can't figure out why!

Does anyone knows what i'm may be doing wrong?

Comment: Putting an instance of a class in a react state doesn't really work. React assumes [state is immutable](https://react.dev/learn/updating-objects-in-state)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the state so your **person.hunger** can be trigger and execute your **useEffect** .

```
const handleChange = () => {
   setPerson((prev) => {
     return { ...prev, hunger: person.hunger + 10 };
   });
};
```

Please see [**LIVE DEMO**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pcnyzu?file=src%2FApp.js)